# Convert Obj to String HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

I am working on an open-source repository. While I was analyzing an HTML file, I found a JSON angular pipe format `{{obj | json}}`. I know this displays it as a json object but is there any way I can convert this obj to a JSON or convert to string or use the output of `{{obj | json}}` and store it in a variable as a JSON or string.

Answer (score 3):

The object itself would be a Javascript object in the `JSON` format.

To convert to string you can do `JSON.stringify(obj)`